# PHP Database Connection File

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

I am trying to create a database connection file so that multiple pages will have a constant connection to the database. I am trying to understand why one set of code works as far as linking to the database is concerned, whereas the other set of code fails. Please help me understand.

Here is the code that works:

```
$db_connect = mysql_connect('host_name', 'user_name', 'user_password');
    if(!$db_connect){
        die('Not connected :' . mysql_error());
    }

$db_select = mysql_select_db("dispatch", $db_connect);
    if(!$db_select){
        die('No database :' . mysql_error());
    }
```

I am able to establish a working connection to the server, as well as selecting a table and running a query.

Here is the code that fails (I want my code to look like this code but I do not understand why this fails to connect to the server.):

```
$db_host = "host_name";
$db_user = "user_name";
$db_pass = "user_password";
$db_name = "user_table";

$db_connect = mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");
```

I even tried this code, and it still fails:

```
$db_host = "host_name";
$db_user = "user_name";
$db_pass = "user_password";
$db_name = "user_table";
$db_connect = @mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "db_pass") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");
$db_select = @mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("Could not connect to database");
```

Please note that I have tried to switch from single quote ( '' ) to double quotes ( " " ) to no avail.

Please help me understand. Please not ask why I don't just use the code that works.  I want to understand why the second sets of code DO NOT work.

Please also note that this is only my second time using Stack Overflow, and I am still trying to get the hang of it.  Thanks.

Hit me back...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained, are [officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) and can be [dangerous in live code](http://bit.ly/4zUdtT). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Do you get an error message in `mysql_error()` when you run the non-working code?

Comment: Yes, I get the COULD NOT CONNECT TO MYSQL error.

Comment: why on Earth do you quote the variables ?

Comment: I just realized the only difference between the 2 non-working codes is I included the $db_select, which doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @user2335979 - no, that's your own error message. If you use `die(mysql_error());` instead, you'll see exactly what error the databse is returning.

Comment: @Twisted1919, I was trying to mimic code from a previous programmer.

Comment: @user2335979 - don't, use your own brain.

Comment: @adrewsi, my apologies. Yes, that was my error message. With that said, I am not receiving any error messages.  I am just not able to connect.

Comment: @Twisted1919, of course I will use my own code, however, as stated, I want to understand why the second set of code does not work.

Comment: Your database is called dispatch not user_table

Comment: @user2335979 - so you've tried `$db_connect = mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass") or die (mysql_error())`, and it's failing at that point, but not echoing out anything at all?

Comment: @Anigel, please disregard the use of the actual table name. I meant to change it to user_table.

Comment: Does anyone see my most recent post? Removing the single quotes completely worked. Would this be a common practice or could this be a fluke?

Comment: @user2335979 - you had the strings wrapped in single quotes in your mysql_connect call? They're in double quotes in your question. PHP treats strings in single quotes as literals, so it uses their actual values; if they're in double quotes, then the value of variables are interpolated instead.

Comment: @Jimbo I doubt he's using PHP RC5.5, but still you deserve the upvote

Answer (score 0):

Try unquoted vars:

```
$db_connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");
$db_select = mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("Could not connect to database");
```

Comment: @xy, wow... That appears to have worked. I then added a query to select from the table, and it also worked.  I wonder why is it the quotes had to be removed in order for it to work.  Would this be common practice?

Comment: Adding the quotes in the first place would not be common practise

Comment: @Anigel, I am not sure if that was a "smart-@$$" response, but I will take that into consideration.

Comment: No, it was a serious comment, It is not common practice to quote variable names in that case. It would only be common practice to quote strings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone is your change your phpmyadmin server Password. so please sure it's right or not.

1> open " **phpmyadmin** ".

2> Click on " **Privilenges** " tab.

3> Now see your Server Username and click on " **Action** " (Yellow color).

4> Now you can change your **Password**.

Try Your Datbase connection with new Password.